# getting ajax request url on the recieving page

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

i have the following setup:

an aspx page called content.aspx

from it i make an ajax request to population.aspx with all the parameters i need and embed the response which is html data  of population.aspx

in population.aspx i have a function that needs to use the parameters and a function that takes them out of the url:

```
function getParameterByName(name) {
    var url = window.location.href.toLowerCase();
    name = name.toLowerCase().replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
    results = regex.exec(url);
    return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
```

when i use it i get the url of content.aspx which does not contain the required parameters.

is there a way to get the request url i used and not window.location?

thanks.

Comment: you mean like `var url = your_url_variable.toLowerCase();` ??

Comment: How do you pass the query strings, if content.aspx does not contain query strings?

Comment: i pass them in the ajax request url

Comment: well i solved it using a hidden field and setting its value to Request.Url.AbsoluteUri from code behind. if any one has a javascript option for doing this i will appriciate it.